# How to create multiple worker threads on a single CPU

Tags: node.js, multithreading, cpu-usage, worker

I am using a multi-core CPU.
I'm trying node.js worker threads to offload work from the main process.

But I'll be deploying this to a single-core system in the cloud.

My question is : How do I limit my worker threads to run on single CPU?

Here's my code,

`index.js`

```js
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads')

console.log(process.pid)

function offloadToThread(workerData) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const worker = new Worker('./fib.js', { workerData });
    worker.on('message', resolve);
    worker.on('error', reject);
    worker.on('exit', (code) => {
      if (code !== 0)
        reject(new Error(
          `Stopped the Worker Thread with the exit code: ${code}`));
    })
  })
}

async function run() {
  // trying to create 1000 threads
  for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    // find fibonacci from 1-20 and then repeat the process.
    offloadToThread(i % 20).then(r => { console.log(r, i) });
  }
}

run().catch(e => console.error(e))
```

worker file `fib.js`

```js
const { parentPort,workerData } = require('worker_threads')

function fibonacci(num){
  if(num <= 1){
    return num;
  }
  return fibonacci(num-1) + fibonacci(num -2);
}

let value = fibonacci(workerData);
parentPort.postMessage(value);
```

Here's the image of all 4 CPU going bonkers.

[image: All 4 CPU going bonkers]

All I need is to use single CPU so that I can optimise it for a single CPU.
Any packages or modules that I should know of?

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: The host OS will decide which CPU a thread runs on. Just as you did not need to specify the 4 CPUs in order for the thread to run on 4 CPUs, on a system with 1 CPU, all threads will run on the single CPU

Comment: The entire point of worker threads is to scale to multiple cores.   Why even use it if you want to run on just one CPU?

Comment: @FredStark I need to simulate this as single CPU using code.

Comment: @BadZen I need to limit the resources, I need to do it at several other places.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see, for performance metrics.    You'll need to use some kind of process affinity feature of the host OS, there's nothing in node that will talk to the OS and request that feature - which may not even exist in some places!  (For Linux, you have `taskset`, in windows you can set affinities from Task Manager...  )

Comment: You could run it in a VM or docker limited to 1 vCPU?